# What should be the return type for the WCF service method having a master-detail Linq-to-entities query?

Tags: c#, silverlight, .net-4.0, linq-to-entities, wcf

I have a service method written as follows for a Silverlight 4 application:

```
    [OperationContract]
    public List<string> GetAll()
    {
       GearsLtdEntities ge = new GearsLtdEntities();
       var query = from a in Employees 
                    join b in Depts
                    on a.DeptID equals b.DeptId
                    group a by b.DeptId into c
                    select new
                    {
                        DeptId = c.Key,
                        Name =
                              from cg in c
                              group cg.Name by cg.Name into g
                              select new
                               {
                                  Name = g.Key
                               }
                   };
        
        return query;
}
```

and I want the data to be returned in this manner:

[image]

Now the query works fine when I run it standalone in LINQPad but when I am confused how to return the results back from the method. What should the method type be? I tried `IEnumerable <DeptEmployee>`, then I tried `IEnumerable <string>`, also tried a class `DeptEmployee` specifically created for this, but nothing seems to work.

### Edit

I looked up projections and WCF data services as well, but couldn't find a single complete example demonstrating these, what I see are fragments and snippets and these aren't helping me get what I want. Is there a complete working example of using a master-detail query in WCF and SL with linq to entities and then returning the result from the service method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a relationship between `Employees` and `Depts` on your edmx / designer?  (You should!)

Why not just return a collection of `Depts`, where each `Dept` has its own collection of `Employees`?

```
[OperationContract]     
public List<Depts> GetAll()
{        
    GearsLtdEntities ge = new GearsLtdEntities();        
    return ge.Depts.Include("Employees").ToList();
}
```

Silverlight can easily retrieve the relevant properties from the objects.

The only reason that I wouldn't do this is if either `Employee` or `Dept` contained a significant chunk of data that you didn't want to send across the wire.  If that's the case then create cut-down classes to represent these two objects.

Answer (score 1):

It is an anonymous type so you need to use projection. I think that this post will help. Thanks.
http://programming4.us/database/96.aspx

Comment: It didn't work. Am stuck in the XML editing of the edmx file where I have to add the correct QueryView and EntityMapping. No matter what I try, it keeps giving error for the entities in the XML editor. Can someone help me draft a entity definition for the content of grouping DeptId with EmpName?